# Accessing current context within JQuery validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a custom JQuery validator which validates if the email entered already exists in the list. I am displaying 3 input fields using foreach in cshtml. So basically I just have one input field in my code. With in my "validator.addMethod", I am trying to access the text field using $(this). But that is returning the validator. Here is my code:

```
$.validator.addMethod("emailTextField", function (value, element) {
        var designeeID = $(this).attr("data-level");
        var newEmail = $("#txtUpdate" + designeeID).val();
        var exists = true;
        $("#emailList" + designeeID + " > .list-group-item > .email").each(function () {
            if ($(this).html().toLowerCase() == newEmail.toLowerCase()) {

                exists = false;
            }
        });
        return exists;
    },
   "Email already exists in the list.");
});
```

I am using 'data-level' to access a particular textfield with the first "this" in the above code. But it returns the validator. If I give in the class of the textfield instead of "this", it is considering all three textfields. I need to access just the textfield that is in the current context.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the element being validated, this should work:

```
 var designeeID = $(element).attr("data-level");
```